# Sockets in C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, sockets, networking

I was wondering whether networking is easier in Java or C++. Because I know in Java networking with sockets and such is incredibly easy, such as doing the following:

```
Socket s= new Socket();
s.connect(new SocketAddress("localhost",8888));
```

and if it is significantly harder in C++ that heavily influences my decision. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, considering Java pretty much has everything right there for you, I'd imagine it's easier in Java.

Comment: It is nothing like that. Networking is the same everywhere, you follow the same protocols and you need the same fields to initiate the data transfer. The libraries are different, but the underlying mechanism is the same.

Comment: Java has a much richer library than the pure standard C++, so if your only criterion is the amount of readily available infrastructure, Java can spoil you. Java is after all much more a *framework* than just a library, while C++ is purely the latter. That said, if you take for instance the excellent Boost library, then you can achieve just as much *portable* and easy-to-author networking code with C++.

Comment: I think this mainly depends on the socket library you are using. I think in C or C++ you can directly write (some of) your memory objects to an output stream (which will write the bytes as in memory), while in Java you really can only write bytes, and must care to convert everything else. Of course, there are libraries helping here, too.

Comment: Socket code is painful no matter language. That's one of life's universal truths.

Comment: @Paulo - What do you mean only you can only write bytes?  You would just create an ObjectOutputStream if you want to write the objects directly.  (Yes, I know it is all converted to bytes in the end).

Comment: Don't forget C++ Windows Socket code vs Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building working socket code in Java is easier than in C++.  Building "good" socket code in either depends more on the developer's experience and skill than on the language.  C++ has [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html) that makes this a bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that Java is generally easier for beginners.  C++ is easier it you want to do low level programming e.g. with pointers.

In Java I would do

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost",8888);
```

which is even easier.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is conceptually more difficult than java, at least you should deal with pointers.. Most of the people has difficulties to  understand pointer concept.. 
Also, you should allocate and free memory, if you use C++, thanks to Java GC it saves you from this burden. I think this is the most superior future of Java against C++ or C.

And your specific question, Java has built-in socket libraries, you do not need a third party for socket operations..

To sum up, C++ is harder and more difficult than java.

Comment: Harder *and* more difficult.  You're ignoring the fact that libraries like Boost can help isolate you from both low-level networking code and pointers.

Comment: The question was about network programming, not a general Java vs. C++.

Comment: @Robin, your concerns has been answered.

Comment: but it still answers *the wrong question*.